# Composition computation

Tags: predicate-logic

I wondered if the computational steps works for all different kind of languages in different word orders? such as SVO, VOS, VSO. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update the tree structure to reflect those different grammars, sure! The abstract logic still works the same.